# Change default Multi-Monitor mode and adjust sound profile if HDMI is connected

Tags: settings

When I connect my laptop to the TV via HDMI the Multi-Monitor mode is "extended" and sound profile stays on notebook speaker.

I can change Multi-Monitor mode and sound profile only temporarily. After unplug and plug again HDMI the settings are gone.

My hope is, that there's a possibility to change the default Multi-Monitor mode permanently and make a setting that the sound profile is changing to HDMI as soon as HDMI is connected.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

As far as the automatic sound change goes a quick look and Ask Ubuntu came up [with this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/395746).

I have not tested this solution but author claims it works with Ubuntu 14.04 meaning it should work with elementary OS Freya as well. All credit goes to him.

Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/hdmi_sound.rules` as root with the content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle"
```

Create a file `/usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle` as root with the content:

```
#!/bin/sh
USER_NAME=`who | grep "(:0)" | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
USER_ID=`id -u $USER_NAME`
HDMI_STATUS=`cat /sys/class/drm/card0/*HDMI*/status`

export PULSE_SERVER="unix:/run/user/"$USER_ID"/pulse/native"

if [ $HDMI_STATUS = "connected" ]
then
    sudo -u $USER_NAME pactl --server $PULSE_SERVER set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo
else
    sudo -u $USER_NAME pactl --server $PULSE_SERVER set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
fi
```

Then make it executable with `chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle`

I tried to make this script as generic as possible, but you still might need to change some lines, such as the HDMI_STATUS file path or the profiles used. You can see a list of profiles by running `pactl list cards` and looking under Profiles.

Note that the script failed for me when I removed the keyword "export" when setting PULSE_SERVER, I think pactl is looking for the env variable

Don't forget to reload your udev rules: `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`